# checking if all elements in a drop down menu are present with selenium testing using ruby?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-rc

HI

how can i check if all elements in an array i created are present in a drop down menu using selenium testing?

i have something like this but dosent seem to work

ANIMALS = ["snake","cat","dog"]

def validate_all_animals_exist(selenium)

```
  ANIMALS.each { |animal| assert selenium.is_element_present(animal), "Expected category [#{animal}] to be present" }
```

end

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the verifySelectOptions call

> verifySelectOptions(selectLocator,
>   pattern) Generated from
>   getSelectOptions(selectLocator)
>       Arguments:
>
> ```
>     * selectLocator - an element locator identifying a drop-down menu
>
> Returns:
>     an array of all option labels in the specified select drop-down
>
> Gets all option labels in the specified select drop-down.
> ```

So it would be

```
assert_equal "123123", page.get_select_options("foo").join(",")
```